# How to randomly generate sequences of 0's and 1's that have an even number of 1's or odd number of 0's?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list, sequence

I want to randomly generate sequences(say 1000 sequences) where a single sequence is of length 100 binary digits and every sequence has an even number of 1's or an odd number of 0's in it. Is there a simple, elegant way to do this in Python that is optimal?

Comment: Any binary digits sequence of length 100 has an even number of 1's or an odd number of 0's in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirement is tautological. Since number_of_1 and number_of_0 add up to 100, then they must either both be even or both be odd. Therefore, number_of_1 is even **or** number_of_0 is odd.

So *any* sequence of 100 binary digits satisfies your requirement.

Use this to generate a single such sequence:

```
[random.choice([0,1]) for _ in range(100)]
```

If you need a thousand, then try this:

```
[[random.choice([0,1]) for _ in range(100)] for _ in range(1000)]
```

Comment: I like this, thanks! Let's say I want to enforce both conditions, so number of 1's is even *and* number of 0's is odd? Is there a simple fix to accommodate this?

Comment: @TeodoricoLevoff: That condition is impossible.

Comment: @Teodorico: No you can't. Since 100 is even, if there's an even number of 1's, then there can only be an even number of 0's in it. i.e. even number - even number -> even number.

Comment: @TeodoricoLevoff If you want the number of 1's to be even and the number of 0's to be odd, or vice versa, the only way to do it is to have an odd number of bits in your value. For example, 101 bits instead of 100.